# SQL Difference Between Parameter and value

Tags: sql-server-2008

Sorry if my heading was a bit misleading but not entirely sure how to phrase it.

Why would there be a difference between the below two statements:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tbl2 ON tbl1.num = tbl2.tbl1Num LEFT OUTER JOIN
      tbl3 ON tbl2.num = tbl3.tbl2Num
WHERE tbl2.intNum = 123 OR 123 = -1
```

AND

```
DECLARE @intNum int = 123
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      tbl2 ON tbl1.num = tbl2.tbl1Num LEFT OUTER JOIN
      tbl3 ON tbl2.num = tbl3.tbl2Num
WHERE tbl2.intNum = @intNum OR @intNum = -1
```

We ran the above two queries and it actually gave us different results? We ended up changing it to a Union to solve the problem but I would really like to understand why this happened.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: difference in terms of output results or the performance results?

Comment: What data do you have in your tables when there is different output? What output do you get from the queries?

Comment: Difference in terms of output. It returns 866 Rows when using the variable but only 14 when using the actual int (123)

Comment: The data is exactly the same in both cases

Comment: Different number of rows, but the same data—not sure whether I understand it well. Do you mean the one returning the bigger number of rows actually contains duplicate rows?

Comment: Can you update the question with sample data that will show the problem you have. I have tested your queries with data I made up and I get no difference in output.

Comment: No Unfortunately not duplicates, it just added extra results. I unfortunately can't post any data due to it being private information and all. What I still don't understand though is why would it matter if it's assigned to an integer or a variable with the same value? I did run some additional queries and it does look like it could be something to do with the fact that tbl2.intNum IS NULL?

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce the behavior you describe with the information you have provided. There must be something else other than that the where clause is evaluated against a constant instead of a variable that is causing what you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the parameter type:

```
declare @intNum int = 123
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a misstype in the code above but was not in the actual query we ran on the server, a bit tired :-)